# [Azure Function]Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions

.Net Core 3.1. I used System.Runtime.Caching library, it depends on System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

But there is a amazing thing happened, I test it in MS unit test project[.NET Core 3.1], it runs well, then in Azure Function project[.NET Core 3.1], it will throw 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.' error, and in project .deps.json, also have dependency configurations[image]

Below is Stack Trace:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 6.0 won't support .net SDK 3.1, so update the "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version to 4.7.0 and any other lower version. and try it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems it missed the nugetpackage System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager inside your application.

I suggest you could install the package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager inside the local and re-publish again.

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've installed [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager] package in project, but the error message still throws up.